# Restoring modified size of wxFrame in wxWidgets

Tags: windows, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets to design GUI in windows. The requirements is, if the user has modified the frame size then I have to store the modified size and use the modified size for next session. I am able to store the size, but still I am getting older size not the modified size  in next session. My window has several children(check, text, label). These controls are put in panel using sizers. Every time the best size is queried and recalculated and `SetClientSize(size)` is called. Is this the reason why the modified size is not reflected?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't save and restore the frame size yourself, use [wxPersistentTLW](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_persistent_t_l_w.html) which does it for you instead, see the [overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_persistence.html) for more information and the "widgets" sample for an example of using it to preserve the frame geometry.

Second, the layout mechanism in wxWidgets is totally deterministic, so restoring the same frame size as during the last run should definitely result in the same positions and sizes being used for the children. If this isn't the case (I'm not really sure about it, you don't actually say what the problem is), most likely explanation is that your size saving/restoring code doesn't work correctly -- and that simply getting rid of it and using the built-in support for this should fix the problem (whatever it is).